# Servicio reactive con spring, error al recuperar por id

Tags: java, spring, rest, servicio, programación-reactiva

estoy creando un servicio y tengo un problema para listar los datos segun al id, lo probe en el postman y dice NO FOUND sin embargo el servicio esta levantado este seria mi codigo.

```
Table("expediente")
@Getter
@Setter

public class Expediente {
        
    @Id
    @Column("id_expediente")
    private Integer id;
    
    private String numero;
    
    private String descripcion;

    private String estado;
    
    @Column("fecha_creacion")
    private LocalDateTime fechaCreacion;
    
    private String observacionmp;
    
    private String titulo;
    
    private boolean copiado;
    
    private Integer plazo;
    
    private boolean diasUtiles;
    
    @Column("fecha_atencion")
    private LocalDate fechaAtencion;
    
    private Integer id_migracion;
    
    private String alertaActual;

}


public class ExpedienteController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ExpedienteService expedienteService;
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<RespuestaExpediente> obtener(@PathVariable Integer id,Mono<Principal> principal){
        return SecurityUtil.jwt(principal).flatMap(jwt -> expedienteService.obtenerExpediente(id,jwt.getClaimAsString(JwtClaimNames.SUB)));
    }
    
}


public class ExpedienteController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ExpedienteService expedienteService;
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<RespuestaExpediente> obtener(@PathVariable Integer id,Mono<Principal> principal){
        return SecurityUtil.jwt(principal).flatMap(jwt -> expedienteService.obtenerExpediente(id,jwt.getClaimAsString(JwtClaimNames.SUB)));
    }
    
}


public class RespuestaExpediente {
        
    private Integer id;
    
    private String numero;
    
    private String descripcion;

    private String estado;
    
    private LocalDateTime fechaCreacion;
    
    private String observacionmp;
    
    private String titulo;
    
    private Integer plazo;
    
    private boolean copiado;
    
    private boolean diasUtiles;
    
}


public interface ExpedienteService {

    Mono<RespuestaExpediente> obtenerExpediente(Integer id, String usuario);

}

@Service("ExpedienteService")
public class ExpedienteServiceImpl implements ExpedienteService{
    
    @Autowired
    private ExpedienteDAO expedienteDAO;
    
    @Override
    public Mono<RespuestaExpediente> obtenerExpediente(Integer id,  String usuario) {
                return (expedienteDAO.findById(id))
                    .map(e->{
                    RespuestaExpediente r = new RespuestaExpediente();
                    r.setNumero(e.getNumero());
                    r.setEstado(e.getEstado());
                    r.setFechaCreacion(e.getFechaCreacion());
                    return r;                   
                });
    }
}
```

Este es el error en el postman

> "timestamp": "2022-05-06T04:19:07.989+00:00",
> "path": "/2",
> "status": 404,
> "error": "Not Found",
> "message": null,
> "requestId": "4c05da8b-8",
> "trace": "org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.resource.ResourceWebHandler.lambda$handle$1(ResourceWebHandler.java:408)\r\n\tSuppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: \r\nError has been observed at the following site(s):\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]\r\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/2""

Comment: yo no veo que hayas declarado la ruta `/2`, agrega mas detalles para poderlo reproducir

Comment: lo estoy dando con el /{id}

Comment: entonces tu ruta esta incompleta, ya que te toma solo el /{id}, revisa la ruta que pones a nivel clase con anotacion

Comment: Parece que desde Postman estés lanzando un GET a /2, en lugar de lanzarlo a 'http://localhost:8080/*nombre_end_point*/2'